# What is this MS Access 2010 End of Statement Error

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have inherited a Microsoft Access 2010 application and have been tasked with adding a search function.  My experience with the MS VBA code syntax is very limited, so I am having a problem building a string to query the data.  This is what I have created.

```
StrSql = "SELECT tblOrders.*, tblFleetVendors.* FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN tblFleetVendors ON tblOrders.VendorId = tblFleetVendors.VendorID"
          StrSql = StrSql & " WHERE (tblOrders.OrderingOrg = '" & Section & "'") And (VendorID <> 774) And (tblOrders.OrderID = " & Req & ")"
```

The Section Variable, which is the first variable in the search is what is failing to compile.  I get an Expected: end of statement error. I have no idea what is needed any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `And` statements should be part of the SQL string.

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect. You can even see in the code you've posted here - look at the colors used for syntax highlighting. Note how the correctly quoted values are in one color and the incorrectly or non-quoted parts are in plain white.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response  the correct syntax is

```
StrSql = StrSql & " WHERE (tblOrders.OrderingOrg = '" & Section & "') And (VendorID <> 774) And (tblOrders.OrderID = " & Req & ")
```